# How do you utilitize Browser.Exists?

Tags: c#, watin

I have been writing WatiN tests and I want to begin to use the same browser instance for all of my tests, but I still want to be able to run one test individually if I need to. Thus I want to make a conditionaly statement that basically says, if there is a browser instance already there pointed to the right URl then use that, if not make a new one. The problem is I can't seem to get Browser.Exists to work properly. Ideally I would want something like this:

```
if(Browser.Exists(Find.ByURL("www.mysite.com")) == true)
{
         var Window = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl("www.mysite.com"));
}
else
{
         IE Window = new IE("http://svrp00008cde/cas/default.aspx");
}
```

However, I can't figure out the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about an hour of messing around with it I finally found the solution. A few answers out there, including one from the maker of WatiN himself seemed to lead me the wrong way. I belive this may be becasue the implementation has been changed and the answer was never updated. Regaurdless, this is how I did it:

```
public static IE CheckForBrowser()
        {
            IE Window;

            if (Browser.Exists<IE>(Find.ByTitle("My Site!")) == true)
            {
                Window = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl("http://www.mysite.com"));
            }
            else
            {
                Window = new IE("http://www.mysite.com");
            }

            return Window;
        }
```

I created a method to call each time I was intializing a new instance of IE. This method looks to see if a window is open with the title I presented and if it is it utilizes that instead of opening a new browser instance. Otherwise, it opens an instance and runs my tests from there.